# Is a comma followed by 'and' grammatically correct?

Tags: punctuation, conjunctions, oxford-comma

Is a comma followed by 'and' grammatically correct?

For example:

> This Agreement, and any and all disputes directly or indirectly arising...

Comment: Commas are not about grammar. They deal with style and semantics. Even otherwise, the 'Oxford comma' has already been talked about here earlier. There are also other cases of [comma + *and*] in sentences. In this case, the comma is not exactly an Oxonian, but meant to group and segregate the expressions -- typical legalese. [...]

Comment: [...] *[Miguel took piano lessons for sixteen years], and [today he is an accomplished performer]*. http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/020204whencommabfand.htm

Comment: @Kris Since syntax addresses structure within the sentence, and commas can be used to distinguish certain structures, for instance defining relative clauses and non-defining relative clauses, I can't go with a blanket 'Commas are not about grammar.' Though I certainly agree that they are also connected with the other areas. And in OP, the usage is an optional reading aid.

Comment: This question would be better if it included a complete sentence.

Comment: @Kris it is not entirely clear that this an Oxford comma... this sounds like a slice of legalease where this may be marking off a subordinating clause rather than a comma in a list.

Answer (score 5):

As others have commented, this is about punctuation, not grammar. Unlike others have commented, this is no Oxford comma, it's the first in a pair of parenthetical commas. It does not matter which word the parenthetical begins with. This opening comma is only wrong if after the parenthetical there is no accompanying closing comma, but you haven't quoted enough for us to see if that is the case.

Comment: +1 I already said "In this case, the comma is not exactly an Oxonian." Unless the closing parenthetical comma is optional, there's no way to treat the instant case as one of parentheticals. The use case requires only as much as the OP has (adequately) quoted to understand the significance of the comma. This is an extremely common specimen where no 'closing comma' is ever seen. I have provided an example and cited a reference which I thought would be relevant and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your quote is likely omitting the secondary comma that marks everything from the "and" as a subordinate phrase.

> You, and your invited guest, are free to have cake.  The cake, and any accompanying ice cream, are not poisoned.